# Is signalR client locked to MonoBtls on Android.Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.android, signalr.client

We transitioned to Lets encrypt for certification signing, and the Android.Xamarin http client does not accept the new certificate, apparently since it is cross signed with both X3(which is expired, but VERY old android clients dont care about the expiry) and X1 root certificate(which is valid, but MonoBtls doesnt care...).

Switching to native httpclient and TLS1.2 in settings for android project fixes this problem for regular https requests, but the signalR connection setup still fails with a reference to MonoBtls:

```
Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY
   at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
```

I tried 3 different ways of specifying that I wanted the native android http client(csproj, environment file and overriding HttpMessageHandlerFactory on the options of the signalR connection builder) but it seems signalR client insists on using Mono httpclient on android?